# How to merge two sorted lists in ascending order without using .sort() on final list?

Tags: python, merge

It's doing it all except for the last one and I'm not sure why.

```
import random
def merge_lists(a,b):
    lst=[0 for i in range(len(a)+len(b))]
    print(lst)
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    print(a)
    print(b)
    j=0
    k=0
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        if j<len(a) and k<len(b):
            if a[j]<b[k]:
                lst[i]=a[j]
                j+=1
            else:
                lst[i]=b[k]
                k+=1
        print(lst)
        print(i)
        print(j)

def main():
    n=5
    m=8
    x=lst1=[random.randrange(0,50) for i in range(n)]
    y=lst2=[random.randrange(0,50) for i in range(m)]
    print("unsorted list 1 is", lst1)
    print("unsorted list 2 is", lst2)
    merge_lists(x,y)

main()
```

When ran, I'm not sure why it's not outputting the last digit of either list `a` or `b`.

Comment: `if j<len(a) and k<len(b)` will fail as soon as one of those tests becomes false.  The usual way to perform a sorted merge is to do the main merging loop, followed by two simpler loops that just append the remaining items for each list.  In Python, those don't even need to be loops.

Comment: im not allowed to use any predefined functions after sort

Comment: So why are you using `print`, `range` and `len`?

Comment: sorry, predefined list functions with the exceptions of sort() once for the first two lists. so im not allowed to use append(), pop(), etc.

Comment: So you have to use lists, but you can't use any of the usual list methods? Not being allowed to use `append` is making this code needlessly complicated, so if that is really a restriction for your assignment, it's actually more harmful than instructive, IMO...

Comment: I guess so, I guess it helps to think critically instead of relying on functions. Anyways, the other comment helped me figure it out with while loops which makes sense.